# How is Power-Up Fusion cost calculated?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

It seems higher level Monsters need more coins to fuse, as base monsters. Is the "Coins Needed" amount simply the level of the Monster multiplied by the number of Material Monsters attempting to be fused with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, times 100 coins.

> "Every monster you add to be fused increases the coin cost by 100 times
>   the level of the monster being leveled up. For instance, it takes 100
>   coins to fuse 1 monster to a level 1 monster, and 300 coins to fuse 1
>   monster to a level 3. Therefore, you will save some money by fusing
>   multiple monsters at once, while your original monster's level is
>   lower."

[Game_Mechanics - Fusion Screen](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Mechanics)